# How to preserve the fonts in PowerPoint?

Tags: fonts, microsoft-powerpoint, embedded-fonts

I used some fonts in PowerPoint 2013 and when I opened that in PowerPoint 2007 in a different PC, all the fonts are changed.

Is there a way to embed/preserve the fonts in PowerPoint so that it opens the same way no matter whether the concerned font is installed in the system or not?

Answer (score 3):

Just go to options > save and check *Embed fonts in the file*

[image: embed font options]

[image: embed fonts]

> ## Recommendations for embedding fonts
>
> - When embedding a font, avoid using Embed only the characters used in the presentation. It is better to embed all the characters in a font so that another user can successfully edit the file, if necessary.
> - Use OpenType (.OTF) or TrueType (.TTF), if possible. OpenType fonts consume the least storage space when embedded in an Office document.
> - Avoid embedding Postscript fonts (.PFB, .PFM) if possible. Some users report having difficulty opening an Office document that has a Postscript font embedded in it.
>
> [Embed fonts in Word or PowerPoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/embed-fonts-in-word-or-powerpoint-cb3982aa-ea76-4323-b008-86670f222dbc)

Note that **not all fonts are embeddable**

> Not all fonts are licensed so that they can be embedded. If a font can be embedded, it will increase the file size of your document by approximately the size of the TrueType font (.ttf) file.
>
> NOTE: Some fonts treat normal, bold, italic, and bold-italic as separate font .ttf files. In this case, the file size of your document is larger when you use bold and italic formatting than it is if you do not.
>
> If a font does not have a bold, italic, or bold-italic version, Windows generates bold or italic from the core font. In this case, the file size increases when you use bold or italic formatting.
>
> Licensing rights for font embedding determine how the font may be embedded in the document.
>
> [How to embed a TrueType font in a document](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/290952/how-to-embed-a-truetype-font-in-a-document)

To check if the font is embeddable click on its name in Control Panel > Fonts

[image]

Comment: +1 for the tutorial style answer.  One caveat:  Only TrueType fonts can be embedded, and then only those that the font vendor has applied embedding permissions to.